# python search and replace with spaces, brackets and underscores

Tags: python, replace

I am trying to search and replace all occurrences of `__field(unsigned int,  a_b)` with `ctf_integer(unsigned int, a_b, a_b)`.

Here the text `a_b` can change with different values.

I tried using regex like this:

```
m = re.search(r"__field\(unsigned int(.*)\)", string)
```

But in the result I get two groups and I am unable to understand why.
I want to include the possibility to have spaces in it, so I used the wild-card detector `.*`.
Is this a correct way of doing search and replace?

I also tried with `\w+`, but it does not accomodate for spaces.

The following also does not work if there are no spaces before comma:

```
m = re.search(r"__field\(unsigned int(\s+),(.*)\)", string)
```

questions:

- why does \s+ option cannot detect zero spaces? any alternatives?
- the search returns two groups instead of one, the first spans entire string while the second is after the comma. why is it so?

I can use re.sub as below:

```
re.sub(r"__field\(unsigned int(\s*),(.*)\)", r"ctf_integer(unsigned int, \2, \2)", string)
```

However this has a problem if there are multiple closing brackets.
For example it doesn't work if the input is `A(__field(unsigned int, a_b, a_b))`, like so:

```
string = "A(__field(unsigned int, a_b, a_b))"
re.sub(r"__field\(unsigned int(\s*),(.*)\)", r"ctf_integer(unsigned int, \2, \2)", string)

# Outputs 'A(ctf_integer(unsigned int,  a_b, a_b),  a_b, a_b))'
```

P.S.: It is being used to convert tracepoints from one format to another.

Comment: a_b is a variable string and I want to extract it. I am not sure if it is possible with str.replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look for everything (`.*`) except the `)`, so `[^)]*`. Which would look like this:

```
import re
string = "A(__field(unsigned int, a_b, a_b))"
re.sub(r"__field\(unsigned int,\s*([^)]*)\)", r"ctf_integer(unsigned int, \1)", string)
```

Output:

```
A(ctf_integer(unsigned int, a_b, a_b))
```

In the code above, I also removed capturing the spaces (changed `(\s*)` to `\s*`) making only one group numbered as `\1`. Also, I moved the space detection to after the comma as that's where it probably should be.

Comment: ultimately I used `re.sub(r"__field\(unsigned int(\s*),(\s*)([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)(.*)", r"ctf_integer(unsigned int, \3, \3\4", string)` but I derived it from your solution.